# Does 2 Peter 1:1 refer to Jesus as "God"?

Tags: greek, 2-peter, trinity

2 Peter 1:1 says the following in the NASB:

> To those who have received a faith of the same kind as ours, by the righteousness of **our God and Savior, Jesus Christ**

Are "God and Savior" two terms for the same Person here, such that "Jesus Christ" is our "God and Savior", or is it that "God" and "Savior Jesus Christ" are two Persons?

I'm looking for an authoritative analysis from the Greek, so please interact with the Greek and provide authoritative sources for your claim.

Comment: This question has already been asked: "[What evidence is there to show that Granville Sharp's Rule is authentic?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/8646/2215)", although an answer is awaited. See also "[Is Jesus called God in 2 Thessalonians 1:12?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/2586/2215)" There's no point multiplying these, I believe, and it would be better to consolidate under the "Granville Sharp" question, imo. The main reason an answer is lacking can be found in its comment trail.